# SPOL Calculated Column Formula Help - Working Days

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

I’m trying to find the solution to 2 calculated column requirements. I have searched quite extensively and have only found partial, or partially working answers.

The two requirements are:

Work out the number of working days between a query being received and acknowledged, and based on that number set a text line to “met” if 2 days or less or “not met” if over 2 days.
Based on the status of another column, working out the number of working days between either the date a query was received and closed, or if it is not closed, the number of working days between the date it was received and TODAY.

I am UK based and weekend days are Saturday and Sunday.

On 1, I’ve been playing with a formula like this, but it doesn’t seem to work consistently over weekends. Some seem to calculate correctly, and others don’t. So if a query is received Friday and closed Monday, it gives me 2 days on some (correct) and 4 on others.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/2c450b0a-4e7b-41f5-88bf-42a43fb34d8b/networkdays-in-sharepoint-calculated-column?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

I haven’t found anything on 2.

My columns are:

**Date received** | **Date acknowledged** | **Date closed** | **Status**

In “Status” I have two closed status of “Closed” and “Closed Transferred” along with 3 classed as open which are “Open”, “Pending Info” and “Tracking Only”

**Examples for 1**

Date received - 1 March 2022
Date acknowledged - 2 March 2022
Output - “Met” (2 working days so SLA met)

Date received - 1 March 2022
Date acknowledged - 4 March 2022
Output - “Not Met” (4 working days so SLA not met)

Date received - 4 March 2022
Date acknowledged - 7 March 2022
Output - “Met” (2 working days as weekend days excluded so SLA met)

**Examples for 2**

Date received - 1 March 2022
Status - Closed
Date closed - 3 March 2022
Output - 3 Days (as status is closed, date closed - date received in working days)

Date received - 1 March 2022
Status - Pending Info
Date closed - BLANK
(Assume today is 4 March 2022)
Output - 4 Days (as status is pending info, TODAY - date received in working days)

Date received - 4 March 2022
Status - Closed
Date closed - 8 March 2022
Output - 3 Days (as status is closed, date closed - date received in working days and weekend days are excluded)

I hope the question is appropriate. I have all these working in excel using NETWORKDAYS but am no familiar with the syntax for SPOL. So I really would appreciate any help or information at all.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Comment: You won't be able to access TODAY in a calculated column. These columns are calculated at time of creation/modification NOT at display. So Today has no meaning in that context and won't accomplish what you want. To have something calculate on display, you'll need to use column formatting. However, it is not currently possible to get the weekday for a given date in column formatting making requirement 2 not possible without a SPFx Field Customizer.

Comment: Hi, Chris! Thank you for this. This is very useful to know. I’d played about with TODAY which looks fine when you execute the formula but haven’t actually looked back at the list in the following days to pick up this nugget of information.  I’m now google what a SPFx Field Customizer is.